# Why to add a : infront of a Vue component attribute?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm new to Vue and asking myself why I often see a `:` infront of a Vue component attribute?

I use Ionic with with and for example in the starter template I have the following:

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header :translucent="true">
    ...
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

Why here is a `:`? The result will be the same if i remove the `:`

Comment: `The result will be the same if i remove the :` Try to access the viewmodel properties without `:` or write some javascript expression to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

`:` is the shorthand for `v-bind:` which is binding the javascript variable to the attribute.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

So regarding `:translucent="true"`, **boolean** value `true` will be assigned to the `translucent` attribute. If `:` is not added (translucent="true"), **string** "true" will be assigned to `translucent` attribute, which will also work because any non-empty string will be converted to the `true` boolean variable internally.

So logically `:` is needed to assign the boolean value.